# Fleximage gem on Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Running a Rails application with Fleximage in Ruby 1.8.7 works fine, but in Ruby 1.9 returned error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fleximage-1.0.4/lib/fleximage/model.rb:340: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.1p376 (2009-12-07 revision 26041) [i386-darwin10.0.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0060 p:---- s:0295 b:0295 l:000294 d:000294 CFUNC  :read
c:0059 p:0060 s:0291 b:0291 l:000290 d:000290 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fleximage-1.0.4/lib/fleximage/model.rb:340
c:0058 p:0084 s:0285 b:0285 l:000275 d:000284 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2746
c:0057 p:---- s:0281 b:0281 l:000280 d:000280 FINISH
c:0056 p:---- s:0279 b:0279 l:000278 d:000278 CFUNC  :each
```

And further very long line of error.

My fleximage is stored as gem, keeping it as plugin returning a different set of errors so I don't bother.

How to fix this?

Comment: I have no idea what this is, but would gladly accept a patch :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Found this [post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/26147) that worked for me.